# CSS3 Transform - Skew

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am trying to create boxes as they appear on this site: http://www.instanthousecall.com/features.html

The website uses Joomla, while I need to do this in WordPress. I've examined the code thoroughly and seems like there is a some JS behind it, but not sure. I also tried to find a tutorial which covers a similar thing, but with no success. Basically, I am trying to figure out if it is possible to achieve this only with CSS, using transform:skew property, where the content and background would change when hovered over.

Comment: What have you tried? This can easily be done without JS http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip (add skew as needed)

Comment: JS is not needed just simple CSS is more than enogh

Comment: Prinzhorn, that's it, thank you!